# DOMPDF wrong line break using p and div tag

Tags: dompdf, laravel-dompdf

I have below text when creating pdf file using DOMPDF but it randomly splits the line when using P and DIV tag.

```
This is a line of text that should not split, actually it will split in DOMPDF.
```

Comment: @KJ Thanks for reply.  I have used a div and inside the div there is text that I have written as above and I want them not to get split but still it's automatically gets a line break from the middle.

Comment: it is A4 paper wide and that text that I have written there is not larger than a line of an A4 paper but still it is cut on half. so I don't know what is the issue.

Comment: I could not find the real problem to resolve it but found a work around to resolve it, I was using div and got rid of the the div and p tag of html and used table instead. now it's good to go but I don't know why it was acting weird. all the margin and css style was Ok along with height and width even there was about 1rem space between those div and p tags, I don't know why still it was messing the layout inside the pdf.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.